# Does Dynamodb have atomic scripts?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Well the title says it. Redis has Lua scripts, in mongodb you can load js scripts. In both cases, running a script will run atomically on the DB/cache. Does Dynamodb has something in that sort? And I don't mean the atomic increment/conditional features that appear in the API but full scripting.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only thing close to what you wrote is the [Transaction Library for DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-transaction-library).

Besides that DynamoDB doesn't allow scripting.